# How to use promises correctly with callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I've this service, it returns a list of students asynchronously using callback:

```
    studentModule.factory('StudentService', function (DB_URL) {
        return {
            getAllStudents: function (callback) {
                var Datastore = require('nedb'),
                    path = require('path');
                db = {};
                db.students = new Datastore({
                    filename: DB_URL + '/students.db',
                    autoload: true
                });
                db.students.find({}, function (err, stds) {
                    callback(stds);
                });
            }; //end return
```

My old way to use it in controller:

```
StudentService.getAllStudents(function(sts) {
    $scope.students = sts;
    $scope.$apply();//notify angular about the change
});
```

This works for me, but now i want to use some best practices. I need to resolve the result in the route before coming to the controller, here what i did:

```
.state('payment', {
    url: '/payment',
    templateUrl: 'frontend/components/payment/views/payment.html',
    controller: 'PaymentController',
    resolve: {
        students: function (StudentService, $q) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            defer.promise.then(function () {
                StudentService.getAllStudents(function (sts) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(sts));
                    return sts;
                });
            })
            defer.resolve();
        }
    }
})
```

The alert is returning data from the route successfully but not from the controller - i get an **undefined** in the controller:

```
paymentModule.controller('PaymentController', function($scope,students) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(students));
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you didn't return a promise to your resolve.

Comment: You also didn't resolve your promise with the data, you resolved it with nothing.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it, i'm new to promises please bear with me. You can also answer the question while i'm checking my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always return a promise to resolve functions, and, when creating a promise of your own, you should resolve it with the data you need to pass along with it.

```
.state('payment', {
    url: '/payment',
    templateUrl: 'frontend/components/payment/views/payment.html',
    controller: 'PaymentController',
    resolve: {
        students: function (StudentService, $q) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            //defer.promise.then(function () {
            StudentService.getAllStudents(function (sts) {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(sts));
                //return sts;
                defer.resolve(sts);
            });
            //})
            //defer.resolve();
            return defer.promise
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I would have instead made the service return a promise, but both options work.

Comment: Yes it will be more clean. this is a time saver for me thanks Kevin!